# how to make a scrollable widget using angular ? it should be horizontal scrolling , should scroll on click

Tags: angular, scroll, widget

When the list of cards exceeds the count more than three, the expectation is that there should be a scroll at the end. There will be an arrow for left and right scroll.

I am new to angular never made widget and dont know how to embed it in my json schema .
just guide me.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You need to provide at least an attempt at this so people can help you with it.